# twig button error with some weird character

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, twig

i want two button in a twig page where it show whether the status is "true" or "false", so i write my code like so, and it is working, i mean some of the part because it is returning whether it is "true" or "false" and changing it's color. But it is also re

```
 <td>
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
             {% if userinfo.stats == TRUE %} 
               {<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs myOn-button" >}
                 {% else %}{<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs myOn-button" >}{% endif %}
                  <button onclick="deleteStuff()">ON</button> 
     </div> </td>
```

[image]

But it is also showing some weird character in the button. Do someone knows where i am making mistake. I need to make two button "ON" and "OFF" which return the stats.

if i remove the---

```
{<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs myOn-button" >}
```

to

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs myOn-button" >
```

it return me ---[image]

so there is no button named "on" or "OFF" ! How i can fix it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove your curly braces around your code like so

```
{<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs myOn-button" >}
```

to

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs myOn-button" >
```

EDIT:

```
<td>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
        {% if userinfo.stats == TRUE %} 
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs myOn-button" >
        {% else %}
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs myOn-button" >
        {% endif %}
            <button onclick="deleteStuff()">ON</button> 
    </div> 
</td>
```

Better way to do it:

```
<td>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
        <button class="btn btn-{{userinfo.stats ? 'success': 'danger'}} btn-xs myOn-button" >
        <button onclick="deleteStuff()">ON</button> 
    </div> 
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer :)

Comment: You're not closing the button tag.. also you could cut down the code using a ternary like `<button class="btn btn-{{ userinfo.stats ? 'success' : ' danger' }} btn-xs myOn-button" >TEXT</button>`.

Comment: Yeah I suggested the ternary operator on his original post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31825924/check-stats-when-the-page-is-load/31826497#31826497